# Scripting with rsync, pulling more than the return status

Tags: bash, rsync

I have a script to backup my images and alert me to the status of the script which gets run every 5 minutes. However, I want to figure out how to identify when rsync was successful, but didn't do anything (no files transferred) so I can not notify when that happens. So line 37 should only print if files were actually transferred. [image: my script]

Comment: You probably want to add `--verbose` and look at the rsync output

Answer (score 0):

Use the --stats argument to rsync and parse its output. e.g.:

```
transferred=$(rsync -ar --stats $src $dest | awk '/files transferred/ {print $5}')
```